# How to get English Wikipedia page titles from Arabic page titles

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia

I want to build a dictionary file of Arabic to English wikipedia titles
"wiki_page_title_in_arabic" : "wiki_page_title_in_english"

I now have a list of all the wiki page titles, how can I get the corresponding titles in English ? Putting in mind the huge size of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the API and query for the property language links (`prop=langlinks`) and fr ease restrict results to English (`lllang=en`). Example: you have the article Stockholm in Arabic: ستوكهولم

Use the query: [http://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllang=en&titles=ستوكهولم](http://ar.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllang=en&titles=%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%83%D9%87%D9%88%D9%84%D9%85)

The result will give you the English title.